# Apple Mach-O Linker Error in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, xcode6.1, mach-o

I was adding new UITableView delegate method in my code and suddenly i got one error while compiling like this .My Xcode version is Version 6.1 (6A1046a)

```
Ld /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Med-emhoezxvdfnzwvfvktteeafyndtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MedTests.xctest/MedTests normal arm64
    cd /Users/apple/Documents/med
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Med-emhoezxvdfnzwvfvktteeafyndtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Med-emhoezxvdfnzwvfvktteeafyndtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Med-emhoezxvdfnzwvfvktteeafyndtq/Build/Intermediates/Med.build/Debug-iphoneos/MedTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MedTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Med-emhoezxvdfnzwvfvktteeafyndtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Med.app/Med -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Med-emhoezxvdfnzwvfvktteeafyndtq/Build/Intermediates/Med.build/Debug-iphoneos/MedTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MedTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Med-emhoezxvdfnzwvfvktteeafyndtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MedTests.xctest/MedTests

ld: file not found: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Med-emhoezxvdfnzwvfvktteeafyndtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Med.app/Med
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried my backup versions too but none of them are working now,please help me

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am also had these kind of issue. Then I create the new schema. Then it worked. Just try.

Change the schema or create new schema
[image]

Comment: thank you for this. I don't quite understand why I had to do this.

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD, TWO MONTHS WASTED TRYING TO FIGURE OUT WHY MY APP CRASHED XCODE. IT WAS THE SCHEME THE WHOLE TIME!

Answer (score 6):

Was completely stuck with this too. Deleting the derived data did not help, nor cleaning the build folder (Product -> option-key -> clean build folder), nor deleting stuff in the Organizer window. In the end I decided to delete the "myproductTests" target (that I never even looked into). That worked.  (Xcode 6.1.1 and 6.3)

Comment: @RickJansen How did you delete this target?

Comment: @codecowboy: Build tab, with the pane "PROJECT", below that are "TARGETS". Simply select a target, right-click and a menu appears with duplicate, and delete.

Comment: @RickJansen thanks, it works great, but what is the problem with test target !!!!

Comment: @AT_AB: sorry, I don't know what was wrong exactly. Xcode is a complicated product, and sometimes things go wrong that mere mortals do not understand. At times trial and error just works.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning and running the project again can also work.

1) Product -> Clean 
2) Product -> Run

No clue why, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project -- > Build Settings --> Testing --> Test Host 
Remove the paths in Test host.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting your Derived data folder might also help

You'll find it in

Window -> Organizer -> Projects (Then select your project)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered "Apple Mach-O Linker Error" when referring to a ViewController's view as `_view` instead of `self.view`.